# How to reduce only a single life in a while loop in pygame?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, pygame, collision

So basically I am making a game in which, if the player touches the enemy, the player loses a life. I tried to do it by:

```
if player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
    life -= 1
```

This code is present in while loop, so it keeps decreasing the life. I just want it to decrease the life by only one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Toni's answer might not work. does the while loop control game play updating? if so, it won't. I think the root of your problem is that the while loop loops multiple times while a single "collision" is taking place. In that case, you could consider adding another attribute that allows only one life decrease per collision, when that if statement is true, set collided=true, when it ifs false, set collided=false. only decrease life when collided and that boolean attribute is false.

Comment: Yes, the while loop is the main game loop, it contains all player movement and updating functions. If you do want, I could share it. And can you please explain your answer a bit more clearly with examples.

Comment: @AtifaOmer Unfortunately, both of the previous answers don't work. So I've added a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute collide to the your "Enemy" class:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # [...]

        self.collide = False
```

Implement the following logic:

- If an enemy collides with the player and `self.collide` is set, do nothing.
- If an enemy collides with the player and `self.collide` is not set, set `self.collide = True` and decrement `life`.
- If an enemy does not collide with the player, set `self.collide = False`.

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    for enemy in enemies:

        if player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
            
            # If an enemy collides with the player and `self.collide` is set, do nothing.
            if not self.collide:
                # If an enemy collides with the player and `self.collide` is not set, 
                # set `self.collide = True` and decrement `life`.
                self.collide = True
                life -= 1
                
        else:
            # If an enemy does not collide with the player, set `self.collide = False`.
            self.collide = False
```

This logic means that `live` is only decremented when the enemy hits the player for the first time. The enemy must leave the player's area for a collision to be counted again.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rabbid76, although your method was similar to bcr 's, his didn't work but yours worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @AtifaOmer in the other solution `enemy.player_collided` is always set. Therefore `enemy.player_collided` toggles between `True` and `False` when the enemy and the player collides.

Comment: I did both the things you told me.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the whole `while` loop for a proper answer. But in general to escape a loop on a certain condition you can use `break` statement. Like so:

```py
if player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
    life -= 1
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem is that the while loop loops multiple times while a single "collision" is taking place. In that case, you could consider adding another attribute that allows only one life decrease per collision.

Add an attribute to the enemy class. For this example, lets call it `player_collided`.

Then your collision check could be updated to:

```
while ...:
  ...

  if player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect) and not enemy.player_collided:
    life -= 1
    enemy.player_collided = True
  else:
    enemy.player_collided = False
```

Comment: Thanks @bcr but this isn't working for me. Do you want to see my code?